# How to call specific textfield from model in templatetag?

Tags: python, django

Sorry if this question is very noobish but I have only been learning Python/Django for a month. I have Googled and searched on Stack Overflow for hours now but can't find a solution to my problem.

I am basically trying to parse a URL from a TextField and then present it in a template.

So far I have:

models.py

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    youtube_link = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I created templatetags/embeds.py with the following code:

```
from django import template
from urllib.parse import urlparse
register = template.Library()
from ..models import Thing

@register.simple_tag
def youtube_parse():
    ytparse = urlparse('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnKaOo67mLQ') # URL test
    return yt_parse
```

And in my html template:

```
{% load embeds %}
{% youtube_parse %}
```

So far so good. The template shows the parsed URL (although it's not very pretty yet).

But what I am having trouble with is calling the field "youtube_link" from the model Thing in embed.py. Basically I want embed.py to do this:

ytparse = urlparse(Get youtube_link from model Thing and parse it)

But I have problems calling youtube_link. I have tried Thing.youtube_link and many other code snippets that I found after Googling for a while, but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to pass the string as an argument to the `youtube_parse` method/filter. I do not know your exact scenario but it is likely that you would save one database query if you compare it to the other answer. I would prefer this solution:

`templatetags/embeds.py`:

```
@register.filter
@stringfilter
def youtube_parse(text):
    ytparse = urlparse(text)
    return yt_parse
```

Template:

```
{% load embeds %}
{% thing.youtube_link|youtube_parse %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working now! I got it working after replacing {% thing.youtube_link|youtube_parse %} with {{ thing.youtube_link|youtube_parse }}